# Proving the derivative of an even function is odd using the chain rule

Tags: calculus, derivatives, solution-verification, even-and-odd-functions

My answer:

Suppose that f: ℝ $\rightarrow$ ℝ is an even function, that is differentiable everywhere. If f is an even function, then we have that f(x)= f(-x). We now take the derivative using the chain rule
$$f'(x)= \frac{df}{dx}$$
$$=\frac{d}{dx}[f(x)]$$
$$=\frac{d}{dx}[f(-x)]$$
$$= f'(-x)\cdot (-x)'$$
$$= f'(-x)(-1)$$
$$=-f'(-x)$$
Since that f '(x) = -f '(-x) we have shown that the derivative of an even function that is differentiable everywhere, is odd.

My question:
Why did my TA not accept my solution? I was asked to use the chain rule and did just that. I don't understand what I did wrong.

Comment: This is perfectly fine. Maybe they wanted you to define explicitly $g(x)=f(-x)$ and express $g$ as the composition of $x\mapsto -x$ and $f$?

Comment: Thank you, that might have been it. I asked my TA for any hints but he said I was so close so I should be able to find it on my own.

Comment: Your solution is perfect; full marks. It's abundantly clear where you use the chain rule.

Comment: Your solution is perfect. I wonder if your TA would accept ${d\over dx}f(x^2)=2xf'(x^2).$ Perhaps your TA doesn't accept mixture of the Leibniz and the Lagrange notations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is correct, if you want to use the chain rule explicitly you should define $\phi(x)=-x$ then you know $\phi '(x)=-1$.
Now we can apply the chain rule within the proof:

$$f'(-x)=f'(\phi(x))=-f'(\phi(x))\phi'(x)=-(f\circ\phi)'(x)=-(f\circ\phi)'(-x)=-f'(x)$$

When the last equation is due to the fact that $f(\phi (x))=f(x)$ since $f$ is even.